# Android Studio crashes when trying to google search words from TextEdit

Tags: java, android

I am writing code where I need to google search item from textedit from previous screen. But when I press the button to search, android studio crashes, what do I do wrong?

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView name;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        name = findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        button = findViewById(R.id.Button2);
        String Name = getIntent().getStringExtra("text");
        name.setText(name.getText().toString()+ "" + Name);
        name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //https://www.google.com/#q=
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/#q=" + name.getText())));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My crash stacktraces:

> D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 17740
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onClick(View)
>   in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined
>   on view class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton with id
>   'Button2' at
>   androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:436)
>   at
>   androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:393)
>   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125) at
>   android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102) at
>   android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801) at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336) at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
>   I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 17740 SIG: 9 Disconnected from the
>   target VM, address: 'localhost:8621', transport: 'socket'

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You do not define an `onClickListerner` for your button.

I think `name.setOnClickListener` must be `button.setOnClickListener`

BTW: Do not use the same variable name in two different cases:
`TextView name;` and
`String Name =`.

By convention variable names should start with lower case character

Comment: Yes, I changed "name.setOnClickListener" to "button.setOnClickListener", and it worked. Thank you, I can't +1 your comment because I don't have 15 reputation.